# Fill an array with random values and then count them

Tags: php, arrays, random, count

Is there a way to do a Random Filled Array that counts and returns the lowest most repeated number? I know I could use the `array_fill` and `arra_rand` but I do not know the correct way to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `array_fill`. You generate a random values and put them in array.

```
<?php
 $arr = [];
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
   $arr[$i] = rand(1, 5);
 }
 $a = array_count_values($arr);
 $b = array_keys($a, min($a));
 print_r($b);
?>
```